# Reshaping a dataframe into 3D

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to reshape an activity recognition dataset into the 3D form to be parsed in 2D CNN. I tried multiple times, but I couldn't figure out how it can be done.

My Current shape of X_train is (1418, 80, 6), and X_Test is (355, 80, 6).
I am trying to do as follows.

```
X_train = X_train.reshape(1418, 20, 2, 1)
```

And I got the following error:

```
cannot reshape array of size 680640 into shape (1418,20,2,1)
```

Any advice on how I can reshape the data into 3d so I can pass it in a 2D CNN algorithm?

Thank you

Comment: Well, 80x6 is not equal to 20x2.  You have to account for all of the elements.

Comment: Dude change your question title. You have written `dataframe` insted of `dataset`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing:

`X_train = X_train.reshape(1418, 20, 2, 1)` on some data that originally has shape `(1418, 80, 6)` python will output the error:
`cannot reshape array of size 680640 into shape (1418,20,2,1)`

This is happening because you are trying to reshape `(80,6)` to `(20,2,1)`
80 * 6 is not equal 20 * 2 * 1.

try changing it to something that would result into the same quantity of 80 * 6 such as `X_train = X_train.reshape(1418, 40, 12, 1)` or `X_train = X_train.reshape(1418, 20, 24, 1)`